# Horizontal alignment of chemfig structures

Tags: chemfig

I'd like to align these two chemfig structures, seen below, horizontally but I cannot get my head around how.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\begingroup

\centering
\setatomsep{3em}\chemname{\chemfig{C(-[:180]H)*6(-C(-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=)}}{Lewis
structure\\of benzene}
\qquad
\setatomsep{3em}\chemname{\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Cyclic compound\\of benzene}

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Example output:
[image: Chemfig structure]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting the chemfigs into `\raisebox{\depth-\totalheight/2}{...}` centres them vertically by moving the box reference point to the half of the totalheight. Requires the `calc` LaTeX package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\begingroup

\centering
\setatomsep{3em}\chemname{\raisebox{\depth-\totalheight/2}{\chemfig{C(-[:180]H)*6(-C(-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=C(-H)-C(-H)=)}}}{Lewis
structure\\of benzene}
\qquad
\setatomsep{3em}\chemname{\raisebox{\depth-\totalheight/2}{\chemfig{**6(------)}}}{Cyclic compound\\of benzene}

\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is an old trick. For boxes with zero depth it is simply `\raisebox{-0.5\height}{...}`.

Comment: Great info, I'm fairly new to TeX :)

Comment: Had to remove `\setatomsep{3em}` and use `\setchemfig{atom sep=3em}` in the  preamble, then it worked!